# do i need to reinstall thinking sphinx for mysql if it was previously installed for postgres?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, thinking-sphinx

I installed sphinx a couple of months back for a postgres project and now I have a project that uses mysql. I tried to remedy this with this line in my environments.rb:

```
ThinkingSphinx.database_adapter = :mysql
```

and I even generated a development.sphinx.conf for this project:

```
source article_core_0
{
  type = mysql
  sql_host = localhost
  sql_user = ***
  sql_pass = ***
  sql_db = ***_development
  sql_sock = /tmp/mysql.sock
  sql_query_pre = UPDATE `articles` SET `delta` = 0 WHERE `delta` = 1
  sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
  sql_query_pre = SET TIME_ZONE = '+0:00'
  sql_query = SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE `articles`.`id` * 6 + 0 AS `id` , `articles`.`title` AS `title`, `articles`.`content` AS `content`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(`tags`.`tag`, '0') SEPARATOR ' ') AS `tag`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IFNULL(`customer_categories`.`name`, '0') SEPARATOR ' ') AS `category`, CONCAT_WS(' ', `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name`) AS `created_by_user_name`, `articles`.`id` AS `sphinx_internal_id`, 3448190970 AS `class_crc`, 0 AS `sphinx_deleted`, `articles`.`account_id` AS `account_id`, `articles`.`internal_only` AS `internal_only`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`articles`.`created_at`) AS `created_at`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`articles`.`updated_at`) AS `updated_at`, `articles`.`views` AS `views` FROM `articles` LEFT OUTER JOIN `articles_tags` ON `articles_tags`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `tags` ON `tags`.`id` = `articles_tags`.`tag_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `articles_categories` ON `articles_categories`.`article_id` = `articles`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `customer_categories` ON `customer_categories`.`id` = `articles_categories`.`customer_category_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `articles`.`created_by_id` WHERE (`articles`.`id` >= $start AND `articles`.`id` <= $end AND `articles`.`delta` = 0) GROUP BY `articles`.`id`, `articles`.`title`, `articles`.`content`, `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name`, `articles`.`id`, `articles`.`account_id`, `articles`.`internal_only`, `articles`.`created_at`, `articles`.`updated_at`, `articles`.`views` ORDER BY NULL
  sql_query_range = SELECT IFNULL(MIN(`id`), 1), IFNULL(MAX(`id`), 1) FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`delta` = 0
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_internal_id
  sql_attr_uint = class_crc
  sql_attr_uint = sphinx_deleted
  sql_attr_uint = account_id
  sql_attr_uint = views
  sql_attr_bool = internal_only
  sql_attr_timestamp = created_at
  sql_attr_timestamp = updated_at
  sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` = (($id - 0) / 6)
}
```

problem is I keep getting this error:

```
Sphinx 0.9.9-rc2 (r1785)
Copyright (c) 2001-2009, Andrew Aksyonoff

using config file '/Users/eumir/rails_apps/hivemind/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'article_core'...
ERROR: source 'article_core_0': unknown type 'mysql'; skipping.
ERROR: index 'article_core': failed to configure some of the sources, will not index.
indexing index 'article_delta'...
ERROR: source 'article_delta_0': unknown type 'mysql'; skipping.
ERROR: index 'article_delta': failed to configure some of the sources, will not index.
distributed index 'article' can not be directly indexed; skipping.
indexing index 'contact_core'...
ERROR: source 'contact_core_0': unknown type 'mysql'; skipping.
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Which version of sphinx are you running ? And have you check searchd configuration ?

Comment: i am running Sphinx 0.9.9-rc2 (r1785) Copyright (c) 2001-2009, Andrew Aksyonoff i also checked my config and it showed postrges. i changed that to mysql but to no avail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've compiled Sphinx to just support PostgreSQL, not MySQL. So you'll need to recompile and reinstall Sphinx. You won't need to change anything in Thinking Sphinx, it's just a matter of modifying your database.yml (which I'm guessing you've already done), and you should be fine.

Keep in mind that by default, Sphinx compiles for MySQL support only. I usually compile it for both MySQL and PostgreSQL, and my configure request from within the Sphinx source directory looks something like:

```
./configure --with-pgsql
```

Hopefully that's all that's needed - unless you have MySQL set up in a non-standard location, then you may need to check other flags - run `./configure --help` to see the various options.

Comment: so ill ave to uninstall my thinking sphinx then recompile for mysql and postrges? is that possible?

Comment: You won't need to uninstall, just recompile Sphinx (not Thinking Sphinx) for MySQL and PostgreSQL. It hopefully should be pretty painless.

Comment: dude thanks for your help! had to reinstall mysql since i was using the wrong architecture but you put me on the right track. thanks man

Comment: This was similar to my problem: Homebrew seems to not install postgres support by default. I reinstalled with `--pgsql` and it worked.